# Difference between <enumtype> and <enum class=""> generation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the difference between creating an enum with `<enumtype>` in `items.xml` and generating it with `<enum class="..."/> ?`

Is the `<enum>` generated class not saved in DB? and acts only as a DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumtype` instances are Hybris enums, whose values are saved in the database. They can be dynamic or static, and their values can be searched in Backoffice.

`enum` instances are plain Java enums, whose values are defined in XML. You can't add new values for them via Backoffice (assuming they are dynamic).